# Unable to push file to git repository

Tags: git

I have created a git repository using "git init". Everything works fine but when I execute "git push" from my host it does not push file but gives following errors.

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master 
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To root@10.111.44.77:/var/cache/git/h.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
```

When I clone this old.git repository to new.git repository using `git clone --bare old.git new.git` and push file to new.git its work fine.

But when I create a new bare repository with `git init --bare` then it does not allow "git add" command. It gives following error:

```
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

With `git init --bare` it does not create a .git folder which it creates with `git init`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you're describing is perfectly normal, and is exactly how bare repos work. I'm not sure what your question is though, because there's nothing to "fix" here.

Comment: @Mat i mean the how can i push my changes to server which i have done on my local machine because "git status" will give "one commit ahead than original/master" until i successfully push it

Comment: @Mat just tell me that for pushing or pulling files i need bare repository and for adding i need non-bare. thats mean for single project i need two repositories?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. If you want to push to or pull from something, of course you need to repos. You can't push from a repo to itself. If you don't need to push or pull anywhere, a single (non-bare) repo works just fine.

Comment: @Mat see i have non-bare repo at server i create a file and commit it. now at my local machine i clone my server's repo and make further changes to file. now how these changes must reflect back to server's repo. using push from local machine says u need bare repo. so thats my question that for pushing this changed file do i need another bare repo in addition to my non-bare repo on server.

Comment: @Mat i am new to git i don't have much knowledge about it

Comment: Yes, in that case you need a three repos, one bare that "gathers" everything, and two non-bare working repos.

Comment: @Mat thanks that was my question and problem

Comment: Am I missing something? Why is everyone voting to migrate this, we have [tons of git questions here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/git)

Answer (score 4):

When you create a git repository with the --bare option, you are creating a repository that does not expect a working tree, just the repository structure.

This means that there is expected not to be an index to add (directly) to.  By specifying this, you are setting up a repository that is expected to be pulled and pushed but not added to with the git add command.

When you do `git init --bare` in your folder, it *is* what you would expect to see in a `.git` folder in a project.

```
branches
config
description
HEAD
hooks
info
objects
refs
```

This is why you are having the problems you are seeing.

Spend some time in the man pages for git.  It is very helpful.  Also, they have a wonderful web page with documentation that shows how to manage bare repositories.  http://git-scm.org

After reading your comments in your question, I see what you are trying to accomplish.

***Edit:*** Yes, on your server you would want to do the `bare` repository.  You would only push and pull to and from there.

You would then have a "normal" repository where you do your work, potentially on more than one machine.  You would do your `git add` commands and your git pull and git push on there.  You will need to add your remote to whatever location your "server" is at.  This is not limited to a *real* server, it can simply be another directory; it could be on a network drive, for example, or a USB thumb-drive.

Git is very flexible, and a good reading of the man pages and documentation is very helpful.